# PyQGIS - ImportError when reloading Plugin

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-3

In QGIS 3.4, I created a plugin through Plugin Builder 3 and always reload it with Plugin Reloader when I make any changes.

When I reload my plugin I get the error:

> File: ".../python/plugins\myplugin\ _init__.py"line 17, in 
>                 from .myplugin import MyModel
>    ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package.

But, if i close QGIS 3.4 and reopen it, the plugin works perfectly with the changes made.

The plugin has no subfolders and is in this setup:

> myplugin
>     ├── _init__.py
>     ├── myplugin.py
>     ├── myplugin_algorithm.py
>     └── myplugin_provider.py

I would like to find a way to reload the plugin without restarting QGIS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is not in the scripts themselves but in the structure created.
Having a folder called myplugin and a file also called myplugin. QGIS cannot distinguish between them when reloading.

When changing the script name, the reload worked correctly.

> myplugin
>     ├── _init__.py
>     ├── myplugin_main.py
>     ├── myplugin_algorithm.py
>     └── myplugin_provider.py

It was necessary to change lines only in the _init__.py file due to the name change.

This error does not occur in version 3.10 of QGIS, apparently the program can distinguish folder and file imports, even with identical names.